# AngularJs indexOf дает undefiend

Tags: javascript, angularjs

`deletingId` должен присваиваться 1 как показано на скрине дебаггера

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http, $index) {
  $scope.notes = [];
  $http.get('includes/get_data.php')
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.notes = response.data.records;
      ////////////////////

    });

  $scope.addNew = function() {
    if ($scope.notes.title === undefined || $scope.notes.title === "") {
      $scope.notes.title = "No Name";
    } else {
      $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "includes/insert_data.php",
        data: {
          'title': $scope.notes.title
        },
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
      });

      $http.get('includes/get_data.php')
        .then(function(response) {
          $scope.notes = response.data.records;
        });
    }
  };



  var edit = false;
  $scope.toggleEdit = function() {
    if (edit === false) {
      $scope.showEdit = function() {
        return edit = true;
      }
    } else {
      $scope.showEdit = function() {
        return edit = false;
      }
    }
  };


  $scope.selectAll = function() { //Select all
    var toggleStatus = $scope.isAllSelected;
    angular.forEach($scope.notes, function(itm) {
      itm.selected = toggleStatus;
    });
  }
  $scope.optionToggled = function() { //Select current
    $scope.isAllSelected = $scope.notes.every(function(itm) {
      // console.log(itm);
      return itm.selected;
    })
  }



  $scope.remove = function(deletingId, index) { //Remove selected
    // deletingId = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= $scope.notes.length; i++) {
      if (($scope.notes[i] - 1).selected === true) {
        deletingId = $scope.notes.indexOf($scope.notes[i]);
      }
      console.log(deletingId);
      // for(var j = 0; j < deletingId; j++){
      //  if (deletingId !== undefined) {
      //   $http.delete("remove_data.php?id=" + deletingId)
      //   .then(function(response){
      //    response.data.splice(index, 1);
      //   })
      //  }
      // }
    }
  };

}]);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" class="container">

  <h1>Your Notes</h1>
  <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="toggleEdit()"></i>
  <div class="add_new" ng-show="showEdit()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="notes.title">
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addNew(title)">Add New Note</button>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group select-all">
    <label class="control control--checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="btn btn-primary" ng-change="selectAll()" ng-model="isAllSelected">Select All
    <div class="control__indicator"></div>
   </label>
  </div>

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="note in notes">

      <div class="item">
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control control--checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="note.selected" ng-change="optionToggled($index)">
       <div class="control__indicator"></div>
      </label>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
          <h1 class="description">{{note.title}}</h1>
          <h1 class="description"> {{notes.indexOf(note)}} </h1>

        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <pre></pre>
  <div class="delete">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="remove(note.id, $index)">Delete selected</button>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте код, который воспроизводит эту проблему. Скриншот не годится.

Comment: `$scope.notes.indexOf($scope.notes[i])` - эту строку можно заменить так: `i`

Comment: добавь пример входных данных в сниппет, которые ты в notes сохраняешь

Comment: Спасибо я уже решил проблему я просто не взял ID из php и не присвоил к `deletingId`

Comment: ну и основная ошибка в том, что ты думаешь, что выполнение зашло в `if`, но судя по всему этого не произошло, так как `selected == false`

Comment: а еще, логическая ошибка в цикле `for (var i = 1; i <= $scope.notes.length; i++) {` если у тебя notes массив - то ты пропускаешь первый элемент с индексом 0, и неправильно пытаешься исправить это внутри цикла: `$scope.notes[i] - 1` - вычитая 1 из **значения**, а не индекса

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы но это все я сам уже догадался после правильного кода php